# How to correctly setup a fishing line physics simulation?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I am making tests with a simple cloth simulation. I am trying to tweak it so that I can have a physics based solution for a fishing line animation. The cloth geometry serves as the fishing line and it has pinned verts to the tip of the fishing rod and to a rigid body that is supposed to be the hook with the lure and sinker. However I am getting strange results and I don't understand why yet. In one of my tests for some reason the rigid body lure flies away because of a wind force that is in another collection. In this test the fishing line tip attached to the lure first waits for a long time until suddenly it updates its position and catches up to the rigid body lure. In another test I set the wind forces to zero and then the rigid body lure just falls but the fishing line doesn't follow it. The technique I used to "attach" the fishing line geometry to the lure was the vertex hook to new object method. What is a good approach to achieve a good result? Right now I'm thinking a physics approach might be too costly and difficult. I think an approach of using bones will probably be simpler and faster. Below are a couple of tests illustrating what a couple of tests looked like.[image: no-wind-fish][image: wind-fish]

Comment: ok, sorry, i am not a fisherman, but if you are satisfied with such an animation here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBlcL.gif i can give an answer how i did this

Comment: here some more tests...[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HpVG.gif

Comment: Hi @Chris, yes those look like the direction I want to go in. Could you please share a step by step on  how you got there?

Answer (score 2):

1. create a cylinder, make sure the pivot point is around the end of one end of the cylinder. Keyframe the rotation.

[image]

2. at the other end of the cylinder create plane, make it small in edit mode, grab the bottom to vertices, press E, move mouse a bit down, click, then CTRL-R often until it is long enough
3. select the top two vertices and press CTRL-H -> hook to new object

3b) create a new vertex group with these two vertices, don't forget to press assign

4. parent that newly created empty to your cylinder -> keep offset
5. give your plane a cloth modifier, pin group from 3b
6. make sure your modifier order is Hook-empty, cloth (and after it maybe a solidify modifier so you can "see" it a bit better)

result:

[image]

of course the result strongly depends on your settings, like:

- speed of rotation of cylinder
- settings in cloth modifier

if you wanna compare settings and result, just select cylinder, plane and empty, press ctrl-c and ctrl-v, then g and move it whereever you want it. Blender is so clever, that it assigns the empty to the new objects (that is just one of million things i love about Blender) and change the cloth settings to compare the result.

result:

[image]